# Separating a string into multiple lines in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to separate a string into multiple lines like so:

```
<cfset qSelect = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
                  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can do

```
<cfset qSelect = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" &
    "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" &
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

That what you mean?

Comment: Or are you referring to splitting a string into an array?

Answer (score 7):

As Adam suggested you can concatenate. Another choice would be cfsavecontent.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="qSelect">
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
</cfsavecontent>
```

this would capture the whole string with line breaks (if that's what you are after).